# How to handle multiple statistics in single hadoop streaming job

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I have to get different statistics from some input data. Here is the mapper that I have supposed

```
label_1 = "tot_lan"
label_2 = "max_lan"
label_3 = "ur_bin"
label_4 = "ur_record

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    line2 = line.split('|')
    lang = line2[-1]
    total_docs_counter +=1

    if lang=='-':
        no_lang_info +=1
        continue

    doc_url = line2[0]
    lang = lang .split('&')
    max_lang = ""
    max_percent = 0

    for num, ln in enumerate(lang):
        if num==0:
            continue
        tmp = ln.split('-')
        lang_id = tmp[0]
        # update_lang_statistics(total_lang_record, lang_id)
        print "%s\t%s\t1" %(label_1, lang_id)
    print "%s\t%s\t1" % (label_2, max_lang)
```

I have given a label to each output so that in reducer I can detect to which category it belongs. then by simple conditional expression in reducer, I can get the required output. It is obvious that inner loop output will be more than outer loop. I have test this locally like

```
cat input | ./mapper.py | sort | ./reducer.py
```

It is working properly but when I run this job in hadoop for someple data, it looks like no reducer action has take place i.e output file contains mapper output. mapper output is not properly reducerd. My mapper is very simple just summing each category seprately. Where is the problem. Is there any other better approch to do the job?

Here is the reducer code

```
def counting_reducer(line, temp, count, label):
    label,name, freq = line.split("\t")
    freq = int(freq)
    if name == temp:
        count += freq
    else:
        if temp:
            print '%s\t%s\t%s' % (label, temp, count)
        count = freq
        temp = name

    return [temp, count]

label_1 = "tot_lan"
label_2 = "max_lan"
label_3 = "ur_bin"
label_4 = "ur_record"

#TMP variables
temp_l1 = None
count_l1 = 0
temp_l2 = None
count_l2 = 0
temp_l3 = None
count_l3 = 0
temp_l4 = None
count_l4 = 0

urdu_bin_record = {}

skip = 0
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith(label_1):
        temp_l1, count_l1 = counting_reducer(line, temp_l1, count_l1, label_1)
    elif line.startswith(label_2):
        temp_l2, count_l2 = counting_reducer(line, temp_l2, count_l2, label_2)


    else:
        print line
```

Comment: it's unclear how input data looks like, what are label_1 and label_2, what is reducer. how do you expect to receive an answer?

Comment: I have updated question